# Is it possible to specify string format with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I just wonder - is it a way to check if the string matches some pattern via TypeScript.

**I don't want to do the checks in the runtime**.

```
//What I have now
public id: string; //can be whatever string 

//What I want to see
public id: IdType; //Some type?
id = '0000-0000-0000-0001'//valid
id = 'whatever'//invalid
```

So is it a way to define string format?

Comment: With regular expressions

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it. Pattern is not a type. You can though add validator to check the value

Comment: @Rajesh But it will be a runtime check, right? I just interested to check it during compilation

Comment: @SergeiPanfilov Yes. That will be a runtime check. Think about this, how will TS know what the value is just by type? TS can check for type but the value is processed during runtime only. So unless value is actually set, you cannot check it

Comment: Not possible yet. There's only [suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) - exactly what you're looking for

Answer (score 32):

This should now be possible as of **TS 4.1 beta**

There's now a feature called Template Literal Types, which looks something like this (excuse the basic example):

```
type idType = `${number}-${number}-${number}-${number}`
const id: idType = '0000-0000-0000-0001';
```

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#template-literal-types

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20201112#code/C4TwDgpgBAlgJgFXNAvFABgEgN4DsCuAtgEYQBOAvgLQ4EnnW1GmU17MPoCwAUAMYB7XAGdgsOAC5xSSFDQByAAzLFVFavVrlARnkBuIA)

Comment: This unfortunately won't work because template literal types allow only concrete literal types https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAlgJgFXNAvFABgEgN4DsCuAtgEYQBOAvgLQ4EnnW1GmU17MPoCwAUAMYB7XAGdgsOAC5xSSFDQByAAzLFVFavVrlARnkBuIA

Comment: Seems to be working in the nightly builds. Might just be on its way :)

Comment: This is now working in 4.1.5: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAlgJgFXNAvFABgEgN4DsCuAtgEYQBOAvgLQ4EnnW1GmU17MPoCwAUAMYB7XAGdgsOAC5xSSFDQByAAzLFVFavVrlARnkBuIA

Comment: How do you make this flexible? Maybe there's more '${number}' groups or fewer? working with paths here.