# Creating a one-way assignable typescript alias for string

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So here's the deal: I have ISOStrings and I have strings. I want ISOStrings to be assignable to `string` but not vice versa. Is there any way to do this in TS?

```
type ISOString = string
const isoString: ISOString = "2021-09-07T11:57:25.914Z" as ISOString
const str: string = "Just a string"
// I would like a compile error here along the lines of
// "Type string is not assignable to type ISOString"
const isoString2: ISOString = str
```

Using objects is not an option in this case since it'll change the way the data is stored in databases.

Answer (score 0):

Just flagged my own question as duplicate. See [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64529732/9225733) TS 4.1 version. It looks like this issue has been addressed by TS. Here's what I came up with (only for UTC ISOStrings):

```
type ZeroPaddedNumber = `${'0' | ''}${number}`
type ISODate = `${number}-${ZeroPaddedNumber}-${ZeroPaddedNumber}`
type ISOTime = `${ZeroPaddedNumber}:${ZeroPaddedNumber}:${ZeroPaddedNumber}`
export type ISOString = `${ISODate}T${ISOTime}Z`
```

now if we...

```
const isoString: ISOString = "2021-09-07T11:57:25.914Z"
const str: string = "Just a string"
let isoString2: ISOString = isoString
isoString2 = str
// ^ TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '`${number}-${number}...
```

Note that if you do it "properly" and create a union literal for every single combination of ISOStrings you'll run into `union type is too complex` TS error.

Comment: `"incoming"` happened a number of months ago. TS4.4 is at the door now.

Comment: ...although I'm not 100% convinced that template literal types answer your question. Here's a different approach https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/

Comment: @spender I really like your comment! Although in this case I need to support the conversion the opposite way. I.e. I don't want type `string` to be assignable to type `ISOString` which is allowed with Flavoring. Many thanks for that link though, it is a very useful thing to know :)